# Setting Security Levels in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have created a split database in Access 2007 and need to set user level security. I don't want the users to have access to any of the tables or queries etc. I've created a form so when the database is opened it automatically opens where the user can choose an application to run. How would I go about setting the security levels for each user?

Comment: Have you read the Jet User-Level Security White Paper? That's the starting point for all Jet ULS. But it's pretty easily crackable so if you need real security, you likely need to store you data in something other than Jet MDBs.

Answer (score 0):

[I found the below links using Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=user%20level%20Security%20Levels%20in%20Access%202007). Bit sarcy but it would always be my first port of call without further info or details in a given question showing research already done.

[MS1](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/help-secure-an-access-2007-database-HA001230187.aspx), [MSblogentry](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2005/10/19/access-12-security-model.aspx)

Comment: Was it helpful or do those posts not answer the question?